# Is there a hidden connection between RH and the golden ratio?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, golden-ratio, riemann-hypothesis, stereographic-projections

I realized today that, considering the circle  $ \Gamma_{\Delta} $ on the Riemann sphere whose image through the stereographic projection is the critical line  $ \Delta $, the affixes of the images of its poles through the stereographic projection are the golden ratio and its conjugate, that are the roots of the equation $z^{2}-Sz+P$ with $S=1$ and $P=-1$. As those poles are antipodal points, the products of the affixes of the images is $-1$. The fact that their sum is $1$ means that one is the image of the other through the symmetry $s\mapsto 1-s$, which appears in the functional equation of $\zeta$.

RH can be reformulated as follows: there is only one circle on the Riemann sphere whose image through stereographic projection contains all the roots of the equation $\zeta(s)=0$. Hence there should be only one pair of antipodal points corresponding to the poles of such a circle.

Does this mean that the meaning of RH is that there's essentially only one possible symmetry (namely $s\mapsto 1-s$) giving rise to a functional equation allowing the analytic continuation of $\zeta$ (and other L-functions as well)?

Comment: I think you're missing the trivial zeros in your formulation.

Comment: And there are functions with a functional equation of similar form, but for which an equivalent of RH does not hold (search for Davenport–Heilbronn function).

Comment: Yes, I should have written "$\Xi(s)=0$".

Comment: Do they fulfill other functional equations?

Comment: There's also the conjugation map $z \mapsto \bar{z}$, which preserves zeros since $ \zeta(\bar{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)} $ (this is the Schwarz reflection principle, and works for any meromorphic function which is real (or infinite) on the real line, and in particular any meromorphically continuable function with a real Dirichlet series). These tell you that the nontrivial zeros occur either in pairs (if on the critical line) or quadruples: if $c$ is a zero, so is $1-c$, $\bar{c}$ and $1-\bar{c}$.

Comment: The RH is a statement about the very complicated functions $\log \zeta(s), \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}, \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ (equivalently about the distribution prime numbers). Unfortunately, we only have access to $\zeta(s)$ (a very simple function). The functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ is a direct consequence of the Dirac comb $\sum_n \delta(t-n)$ being its own Fourier transform, equivalently of the Poisson summation formula applied to $e^{-\pi t^2}$, equivalently of the Fourier series main theorem $f(t) = \sum_n c_n e^{2i \pi nt}$ applied to $\sum_n e^{-\pi (t-n)^2 x}$

Comment: @Chappers:I know that. What I ask is whether functions that fulfill the same kind of functional equation than $\zeta$ without fulfilling RH fulfill other functional equations than the "trivial" ones we already know and that you mentioned. For example are there domains $A$, $B$, $D$ whose reunion is the whole complex plane with maps not necessarily of order 2 $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that, say, $\sigma(A)=B$ and $\tau(B)=D$, or any other kind of relations we may imagine?

Comment: What I have on mind is that the functions that fulfill RH only have $s\mapsto 1-s$ and the complex conjugation as symmetries and that their vanishing forces those two symmetries to coincide, thus leading to $s\mapsto 1-\bar{s}$, hence my phrasing "only one possible symmetry".